# Element counting issue

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int countLetters(char text[], char letter);

int main()
{
    char letter;
    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> letter;
    cin.ignore();
    char text[1024];
    cout << "Enter text: ";
    cin.getline(text, 1024);
    int letterCount = countLetters(text, letter);
    cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << letterCount << endl;

    return 0;
}

int countLetters(char text[], char letter)
{
    int letterCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= text[i]; i++)
    {
        if (letter == text[i])
        letterCount++;
    }

    return letterCount;
}
```

This code, as written, is designed to ask the user for, first, the letter they want to search for in a line of text. Second, it will ask the user to input the line of text they want to have searched. Finally, it will spit out how many letters there are in the specific line of text they input.

My specific error lies here: when user asks for 'e' in "CS 124 - Introduction to Software Development", program only declares that there is one 'e' . I'm unsure what's wrong, because when you run the program and input 'o' while asking to search the exact same line of text, you get the proper number of 'o' values returned, 4. 
Any ideas as to what my error is and why it glitches when searching for 'e' ?

Comment: Your `for` condition is wrong, the `for` loop should continue until it is less-equal to `text`'s length not the value of `text[i]`. Since this is C++ you should use `string`s not character arrays, why make it harder on yourself?

Comment: What is `i <= text[i]` supposed to test?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the tips! I built on Jonathan Wakely's and Jonny Henly's advice, and in the letter counting function I changed "for (int i = 0; i <= text[i]; i++) into "for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++) and the code works now for "CS 124 -Introduction to Software Development" and counting the e's!

Comment: That's still somewhat incorrect, as long as `text[i]` does not equal `0` then your `for` loop will continue. This just happens to work in this scenario since `getline` returns a c-string (array of characters with a trailing null escape (`\0`)). You're using C++ but taking the C approach, you should implement your code with regard to C++.

Comment: What should I put in there to make sure my for function uses a string and not an array? Putting in text[size],  didn't work for it, nor did leaving it blank as in text[] , size meaning any arbitrary value.

Comment: I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` condition is wrong, the `for` loop should continue while `i` is less than `text`'s length not the value of `text[i]`. Since this is C++ you should use `string`s not character arrays, why make it harder on yourself?

The code below is a C++ approach, note that my C++ is a bit rusty and the code might contain errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int countLetters(string text, char letter);

int main() {
    char letter = ' ';
    string text;

    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> letter;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter text: ";
    getline(cin, text); // use 'getline(cin, text)' instead of 'cin >> text'

    int letterCount = countLetters(text, letter);
    cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << letterCount << endl;

    return 0;
}

int countLetters(string text, char letter) {
    int letterCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        if (letter == text[i]) {
            letterCount += 1;
        }
    }

    return letterCount;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, apart from the `string text("");`. Why not just use the default constructor? Why initialize it with a string that needs to be counted with `strlen` and decide whether or not to allocate memory to hold it, when you just want an empty string (which is about to be overwritten by the user input anyway).

Comment: Alright, I put that all in there, and it appears that for (int i = 0; i <= text.size()) the counter actually stops counting at the end of the first word. I input letter "o" and separate inputs "frog" and "froog," and the it counted 1 and 2 as intended. However, when I typed "o" and then "frog hopped over the bog," it only counted the o in the first word.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's been a while since I've written any C++ code so I was looking at CppReference's `string` page and thought that `string str ("")` was the new norm for creating a string. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Also is the cin.ignore() call still necessary?

Comment: Yes, it's needed to consume the newline character after the first letter entered. But your `cin >> text;` only reads a single word, up to the next whitespace. You want `getline(cin, text);`

Comment: @JonathanWakely was just looking that up, I was going to use `getline` with a while loop but will instead use what you suggested.

Comment: @JonathanWakely and Johnny Henly It works good now when combined with the getline(cin, text) ! Properly counted the o's and such, along with everything else!

Answer (score 0):

**change the condction**

```
i <= text[i]
```

to

```
text[i] != '\0'
```